# How to find the duplicates in an array in O(1) time in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, sorting, compare-and-swap

I am given a task to find the duplicates in an int array in O(1) time. **My approach is to first sort the array and then find the duplicates using a linear search.** I first used to sort the array by the swapping the numbers like this:

```
for(int i = 0;i<ar.length;i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < ar.length; j++) {
        if (ar[i] > ar[j]) {
            buk = ar[i];
            ar[i] = ar[j];
            ar[j] = buk;
        }
    }
}
```

but the efficiency of this algorithm is **O(i*j)** which is not required for the solution.  I have tried to use recurssion for sorting the array:

```
static int x = 0;
static int[] swap(int[] arr) {
    if (x >= arr.length)
        return arr;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i - 1] > arr[i]) {
            int bucket = arr[i - 1];
            arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = bucket;
        }
    }
    x++;
    arr = swap(arr);
    return arr;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working at the moment. Please provide suggestions/alternate methods to sort an array, I have encountered this problem many times.

The Question is: find one number that repeats in linear time using less than O(n) space and traversing the stream sequentially O(1) times.

Comment: Do you mean O(n)?

Comment: With an array, finding a value (or in your case, two) will always be bigger than `O(1)`, the minimum you could have have is `O(log n)` with a binary search on a sorted array.. but to find duplicated values, this requires to iterate the value to check them..

Comment: Best you can get sorting is O(n*log(n)), but never O(1). Searching in an Array cannot be performed in O(1), best O(log(n)) if using binary search (has to be sorted). Finding duplicates... I guess O(n) in worst case on a sorted array.

Comment: I've found [this algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-duplicates-in-on-time-and-constant-extra-space/) for sorting in O(n) time and O(1) space. I doubt you can get better than that.

Comment: precompute histogram (`O(n)`) then checking if value `x` is duplicated in array is `O(1)`

Comment: @Amongalen: For an array of size `n` this approach only works if every element in the array is in range `0,...,n-1`, but there's no hint in this direction in the question.

Comment: "... traversing the stream sequentially O(1) times" What does that even mean?

Comment: "traversing the stream sequentially O(1) times" is O(n), not O(1), time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is mathematically impossible to find duplicates in `O(1)`.  You have to examine all `N` elements of the array *at least once* to test if each one is a duplicate.  That is *at least* `N` operations, so the *lower bound* on the complexity is `O(N)`.

Hint: you can do it in `O(N)` if you use (say) a `HashSet` to record each value that you have already seen.  The snag is that a `HashSet` is a space-hungry data structure.

---

> Please provide suggestions/alternate methods to sort an array, I have encountered this problem many times.

The simply way to sort an array of integers is to use `Arrays::sort(int[])`.  That will be `O(NlogN)`.

It is theoretically possible to sort an integer array in better than `O(NlogN)`, but only if you can place a bound on the range of the integer.  Lookup up [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).  The complexity is `O(max(N, R)` where `R` is the difference between the smallest and largest numbers.  The catch is that `O(R)` could be much larger than `O(N)` ... depending on the inputs.

But if you know that `M` is likely to be less than `NlogN`, you can use a variant of count sorting and use only `O(M)` bits of extra space to de-duplicate the array in `O(max(M, N))`.  (I will leave you to figure out the details.)